# How to associate the values of a column to another column of a different data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two different data frame, in one of them I have the information `id` , in the other I have the `id` and a vector `n`, I would like associate the values of `n` to `id` in the first dataframe. 
for exemple:

```
 df1 <-data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3)
  )
df2 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
   n = c(5,9,8)
  )
```

I would like as output:

```
df1:

id   n
1    5
1    5
1    5
2    9
2    9
3    8
3    8
3    8
3    8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("id") )
```